# Remove anonymous methods from TThread Queue

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe

From within a thread I queue events to run in the context of the main thread like this :

```
TThread.Queue(nil, procedure begin AddDataToChart(SomeData) end);
```

Now at some point I need to dequeue these events as the component that is addressed in the anonymous method is destroyed and hence should not receive more data. I know that I can dequeue events from the TThread synclist by calling [TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents). Unfortunately this seems to only work for Thread methods, but not for queued anonymous methods. So my question is how to remove my anonymous methods from the queue.

Comment: Can you put in validation check before calling `AddDataToChart`? A simple global (in scope) boolean would suffice.

Comment: @LU RD I actually thought about this, but found this solution a bit dirty. I think removing the queued events would be cleaner thus not running the AddDataToChart code in the first place.

Comment: maybe you can do better with some another threading library like OTL ? Or you can make a dedicated `TThreadQueue<TProc>` of those anonymous methods explicit and check it from Application.OnMessage

Comment: @Arioch I know that I could use a completely different threading approach, but I thought it would be possible to remove the queued anonymous methods which would have been the simplest solution to my problem. Since this is not possible, at the moment I stick with LURD suggestion, although I don't really like. But on the other hand it works and is the most parsimonious solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TThread` does not expose any way to remove queued anonymous procedures. The only option would be to queue your anonymous procedures using a dedicated `TThread` object (call the non-`class` version of `TThread.Queue()` method on that object, or pass that object as the `AThread` parameter to the `class` version of `TThread.Queue()`), then you can pass that object to the `TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents()` method that takes a `TThread` object as input.